# How to use a Video as text background in css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to use a Video as Text-Background in css?
I know you can use Images and gifs using

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

but gif's are just too low quality.

edit: I want the letters as a video, Sorry if I have expressed myself wrong.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Do you want a background behind your text or the letters of your text as a video?

Comment: I want the letters as a video, Sorry if I have expressed myself wrong

Comment: what do you mean by letters as a video ?

Comment: this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5ouCC.png but with a video.

Comment: create video of that text and show like in my answer!

Comment: okay, i just hoped i could do it just using css with dynamic text but that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with

```css
#one {
    position: absolute;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
div {
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <video id="one" autoplay poster="image.png">
        <source src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
     <h1>Bunny is funny</h1>

    <p>Hello i love bunny and its not funny</p>
</div>
```

`z-index` will make it behind the all element

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using mix-blend-mode. It doesn't work in IE, but it is compatible with all other modern browsers.

I'm using an embedded vimeo clip here, but you can just put a video and replace the css label accordingly (change from iframe to video).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text-video {
  position: relative;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-video .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-video .text p {
  font-size: 12vw;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-video">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/134967947?autoplay=1&loop=1&muted=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen;"></iframe>
  <div class="text">
    <p>VIDEO TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```